# node replace function behaving differently than core javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to replace Apostrophee(') with (\')

```
In Javascript
Code :
    var str = "hi'ee"; 
    var res = str.replace("'", "\\'");
Result : "hi\'ee"
```

But

```
In Nodejs in Webstorm
    var str = "hi'ee"; 
    var res = str.replace("'", "\\'");
Result : "hi\\'ee"
```

why node puts extra slash in result

Comment: Are you sure this is not simply a matter of the way you are observing the two values? Have you compared `res.length` for both values?

Comment: firefox console shows length = 6 shows "hi\'ee" ,linux terminal shows length = 6 shows "hi\'ee"  , webstorm shows length = 6 but shows "hi\\'ee"

Comment: Then there is no problem. They are all the same value, just displayed differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. They are just being shown differently in whatever manner you are observing the values.

Execute this in both environments:

```
var str = "hi'ee"; 
var res = str.replace("'", "\\'");
console.log(res);
console.log(res.length);
```

You will see that the output is

```
hi\'ee
6
```

in both cases.

Comment: in linux terminal it is working fine but in webstorm it is giving -  hi\\'ee

Comment: firefox console shows length = 6 shows "hi\'ee" ,linux terminal shows length = 6 shows "hi\'ee" , webstorm shows length = 6 but shows "hi\\'ee"

Comment: @vijay Then there is no problem. They are all the same value, just displayed differently.

Comment: @vijay Any reason you un-accepted my answer after all this time?

Comment: actually i am **blocked from asking question** due to irrelevant questions , helpless questions  . due to that i was on verge to delete this question.so while deleting this question i thought if i un-accept i will be able to delete the question.but i was not able to delete , at last to delete this question i have raised flagged of which i haven’t received response till now. reply me if go wrong some where :)

Comment: @vijay You shouldn't simply un-accept correct answers. That's one place where you went wrong. Were you provided with any information about how you can get the block removed? I don't think that deleting questions with upvoted answers is the way to do that.